# Set whose subsets are all convex

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for a metric space in which all subsets are convex sets.
I tried to find examples of such sets, but didn't find any so far.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to define a convex set you need two operations on your space (i.e, it has to be a vector space), since a set $C$ is convex iff $tC+(1-t)C = C$. And given a vector space with two distinct points $x\neq y$, take $A=\left \{x, y\right \}$ is not convex.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend the definition to riemannian manifolds? So we say that a set $A$ is convex if for any geodesic segment between two points in $A$, the segment is contained in $A$.

Comment: I am not familiar with riemannan manifolds but we are defining a set A to be convex iff any geodesic segment between any two points of A is in A. A segment does not answer the question because it contains distinct points whose union is not necessarily convex.

Comment: Yeah, it is completely possible, but it carries the following name: "geodesically convex set". The ideia is exatcly that one you were talking ! But for your questions my answer is enough, since the same set I have writen will be an example.

Comment: Thank you. May be I don't have to have a vector space either? May be I only need a metric space to define a convex since a segment can be expressed in terms of distance only.

Answer (score 0):

A metric space with exactly two points cannot be convex, therefore you are looking for the space of a single point.

Comment: So it is only true for some subsets and not all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about ({0,1},HD) where HD is the Hamming distance? The empty set, {0}, {1} and the segment [0,1] are all convex, right?